# Let $R$ be a UFD, and let $f(X) \in R[X]$ be a primitive polynomial. Prove that if $g(X) | f(X)$, then $g(X)$ is primitive.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let $R$ be a UFD, and let $f(X) \in R[X]$ be a primitive polynomial. Prove that if $g(X) | f(X) \in R[X]$, then $g(X)$ is primitive.

Attempted Proof:
Since $f(x)$ is primitive, its coefficients do not have a gcd, hence, f(x) cannot be expressed as $f(x) = c \times h(x)$ where c is a constant. Assume that g(x) is not primitive, then g(x) can be expressed as $d \cdot k(x)$. Since $g(x) | f(x)$, $f(x) = g(x) h(x) = d \cdot k(x) h(x)$. Contradiction.

I don't know why I just have a feeling that it is not quite right. Or is there any more elegant way of doing it? Thanks

Comment: At least I don't see any flaw

Comment: I guess it's fine, though "do not have a gcd" sounds weird. I'd rather suggest to talk about $c$ and $d$ being units or non-units of $R$.

Comment: $c\mid g\mid f\,\Rightarrow\, c\mid f\,\Rightarrow\, c\mid 1,\,$ by $f$ primitive.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite right. The only problem is that its coefficients has a gcd w/c is 1 (Definition of a primitive polynomial). But the rest of the proof is correct.